# Google Cloud Storage vs. HDFS

Tags: google-cloud-storage, hdfs, google-cloud-dataflow

In HDFS, you can create a file that has many partitions. This made me start thinking on a few questions for google cloud storage

1. Can I do the same in Google Cloud Storage spreading out my file across many nodes?
2. Can I create a file with say N empty partitions and have N nodes filling in each partition?

As our data flows through the system to the end, this allows us to map any size file a customer gives us to a single output file (even though the output file is spread over a cluster of nodes).

hmmm, thinking out loud, I am not sure how to do this in Hadoop except via map/reduce.  Is there a way in hadoop HDFS to

1. Create a file of N empty partitions
2. Have my N nodes write to those partitions

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are implicitly assuming things about GCS in your question, like it is implemented more-or-less like HDFS, or that it supports partial writes, like filesystems do.  That is not the case, GCS is a blob (or object) storage system, not a filesystem.  I will try to answer your direct questions the best I can, but this preamble hopefully helps:

> Can I do the same in Google Cloud Storage spreading out my file across many nodes?

You cannot control how GCS allocates objects (or portions of an object) across nodes.  Having said that, GCS automatically splits large objects across many "nodes", both for performance and redundancy reasons.

> Can I create a file with say N empty partitions and have N nodes filling in each partition?

Objects are immutable in GCS.  Once you create them, you cannot change them (you can create new versions).  In short, no, you cannot do *exactly* what you are asking, but you can do things that have similar effect, for example:

1. You can have N processes each creating their own object, and then
2. Compose these objects into a larger object, this is a pure server-side operation, so it is very efficient.

Note that compose is limited to 32 objects at a time, but you can recursively build larger and larger objects with multiple compose operations.

Comment: Thanks @coryan, this is helpful.  I didn't assume but rather asked as I was actually thinking it did not behave like HDFS.  Assuming would mean I would not even ask the question.  Anyways, +1 and a correct checkmark as a thankyou!!!